# Weird email contents on Blackberry mail client

Tags: email, blackberry, outlook

When one of my Mac OS X users sends an email using Outlook 2011 (exchange account) to another one of my users, that user see such contents:

```
0 0 1 8 48 Company Name 1 1 55 14.0 Normal 0 false false false false EN-US JA X-NONE
```

The receiving user only sees it when he views the email on his blackberry.

What language is this?  Why is it showing up?

"Company Name" is actually their company name which I am not at liberty to share.

When I search all over google for this I get tons of matches because it is in lots of code, but nothing explaining what the code means exactly or how I might go in and change the company name.

Any leads here would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the email headers, normally hidden from view as the mail client know to identify and hide them.

Looks like local problem with the mail client installation on his specific Blackberry, I won't worry too much about it.